# Split into new line of this variable

Tags: javascript, html

how to split into a new line of this variable "textToSave"

```js
function saveTextAsFile() {
  var textToSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
  var textToSave = textToSave + document.getElementById("inputTextToSave1").value;
  var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], { type: "text/plain" });
  var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
  var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
  downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to split, than you can concatenate these lines with the next line character:

```
var textToSave = textToSave + "\n" + document.getElementById("inputTextToSave1").value;
```